# Saving changes to a Case in the Console closes the main tab

Tags: case, service-cloud-console

When trying to edit a case in the Service Cloud Console, using the save button closes the primary tab housing the case. Is there a way to prevent this from happening or a workaround to keep the tab open after editing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you edit the Case in console in a primary tab and save it, it must be redirected to Case detail page and should not close the tab. This is standard salesforce feature. Please make sure that you've not override the save button and as well check if you are adding any custom component which causing issue while loading.